# How to copy Files from one directory to another(using DGV) C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, copy

I am working on a program that creates folder templates, and populates them with files the user picks using a `OpenFileDialog`. The user fills out a text field, and a drop down menu (populated by folders in a directory), then adds files to a list. Once the files are added I populate a `DataGridView` with the files. In one of the columns we have a drop down to pick a selection.

The user must make a selection or they get notified with a pop up `MessageBox` instructing them to do so.

The program uses the first column of `DGV` to store and then pull the file path.

All is at a working state, until the program gets to the `File.Copy` line. It is my assumption that it does not like the last line of the `DGV` which is empty. I have tried several different ways that I have come to online. I have tried using the following ideas:

`if (row.IsNewRow != true)` apparently the newest line added is identified with `isNewRow`, however that hasn't worked yet

`if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells["HiddenFiles"].Value) != "")` assuming the default value is `""` then I had hopes this too would work.

`dgv_ListofFiles.AllowUserToAddRows = false;` also tried this approach, I set it to true, just when I want to add my files, then turn it back off so that there are no extra lines.

None of these work so far. Hoping I can get some assistance. Below is the full code, and a screen shot of the GUI

```C#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Quote_Folder_Creator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> FileNameList = new List<string>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void btn_AddFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgv_ListofFiles.AllowUserToAddRows = true;

            //opens file dialog box to add multiple files of various types to list to be added to folder

            using (OpenFileDialog oFD = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                oFD.InitialDirectory = "L:\\1 Quote to Job\\Quoting";
                oFD.Multiselect = true;

                if (oFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //get the path of specified file

                    foreach (var filename in oFD.FileNames)
                    {
                        FileNameList.Add(filename);
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (var newFile in FileNameList)
            {
                int rowId = dgv_ListofFiles.Rows.Add();

                // Grab the new row!
                DataGridViewRow row = dgv_ListofFiles.Rows[rowId];

                // Add the data
                int pos = newFile.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1;
                row.Cells["FileName"].Value = newFile.Substring(pos, newFile.Length - pos);
                row.Cells["HiddenFiles"].Value = newFile;
            }
            dgv_ListofFiles.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        }
        
        private void btn_CreateFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Creates folder structure and adds all files to their respective folders
            



            //check if all selections have been made
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_ListofFiles.Rows)
            {
                //skip last row as it is empty
                if (row.IsNewRow != true)
                {


                    //check drop down for customer to go into or add the folder
                    string customerFolder = "L:\\1 Quote to Job\\Quoting\\" + cmboBox_Customer.Text + "\\";
                    //then create a quote folder based off the quote input box
                    string dir = customerFolder + txtBox_QuoteNumber.Text;
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                    //create the template of folders
                    string printsFolder = dir + "\\" + "1. Prints";
                    string drawingsFolder = dir + "\\" + "2. Drawings";
                    string subContractFolder = dir + "\\" + "3. Sub Contract Quotes";
                    string quoteFolder = dir + "\\" + "4. Quote to Customer";
                    string emailsFolder = dir + "\\" + "5. Emails with Customer";

                    Directory.CreateDirectory(printsFolder);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(drawingsFolder);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(subContractFolder);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(quoteFolder);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(emailsFolder);


                    string destinationFolder = "";
                    //disperse the files into appropriate folders based on dropdown selection in DGV
                    if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells["HiddenFiles"].Value) != "")
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToString((row.Cells[1]) as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).ToString() == "1. Prints")
                        {
                            destinationFolder = printsFolder + "\\";

                        }
                        if (Convert.ToString((row.Cells[1]) as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).ToString() == "2. Drawings")
                        {
                            destinationFolder = drawingsFolder + "\\";

                        }
                        if (Convert.ToString((row.Cells[1]) as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).ToString() == "3. Sub Contract Quotes")
                        {
                            destinationFolder = subContractFolder + "\\";

                        }
                        if (Convert.ToString((row.Cells[1]) as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).ToString() == "4. Quote to Customer")
                        {
                            destinationFolder = quoteFolder + "\\";


                        }
                        if (Convert.ToString((row.Cells[1]) as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).ToString() == "5. Emails with Customer")
                        {
                            destinationFolder = emailsFolder + "\\";
                        }
                        if (Convert.ToString((row.Cells[1]) as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).ToString() == "")
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Please pick a selection for each file added!");
                        }
                        File.Copy(Convert.ToString(row.Cells["HiddenFiles"].Value), destinationFolder);


                    }
                    //clears the forms for the next quote / resets all fields
                }   
            }
            

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //populates the customers dropdown with all subfolders in the quoting folder
            string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories("L:\\1 Quote to Job\\Quoting").Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();
            cmboBox_Customer.DataSource = folders;
        }

        private void dgv_ListofFiles_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.Cells["HiddenFiles"].Value = "";
        }
    }

    public class NewFile
    {
        public NewFile(string filepath, string subfolder)
        {
            Filepath = filepath;
            SubFolder = subfolder;
        }
        public string Filepath { get; set; } 
         string SubFolder { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]